# Clear a Textfield if two are completed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm writing an app for iOS where I have 3 values, and every value is the result of two the others two. So, if you compile two of the three you have the third value. 
Right now I have to clear the value inside the Texfield manually before calculate the third value otherwhise the app dont work. What I want to do is that when I compile the first and the second textfield the third clear automatically.
In practise I want to check the last two entered textfield and clear the other.

How can I check this statement in swift?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to use TextFieldDelegate for this, in the case you are training to display this may help

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate  //set delegate to class 

@IBOutlet var TF1: UITextField 
@IBOutlet var TF2: UITextField 
@IBOutlet var TF3: UITextField              

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TF1.delegate = self                  //set delegate to textfile
    TF2.delegate = self                  //set delegate to textfile
    TF3.delegate = self                  //set delegate to textfile
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method

}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  //delegate method
    return false
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
  textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if(TF1.text != "" && TF2.text != ""){
         TF3.text = ""
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you